# SQL group Query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server

I am very new in SQL. I have a problem as below, Please help. I want to create new column 'exact' if the weather says one of row values as 'hot' then it should should be blank in the new column 'exact'. if all values in the weather says 'cold' it should say 'good' in the new 'exact' column. please let me know if you have any questions.

```
city weather
a     Cold
a     Hot
a     warm
b     Cold
b     Hot
b     warm
c     Cold
c     Cold
c     Cold
```

Comment: Given your sample data, are the expected results only to show `good` where `city = c` and blank for all the other rows? If not, what are your expected results?

Comment: I am expecting only city C to show as good, will that results appear from below code?

Comment: You should try them to find out, but I don't believe in the format you're looking for.  That's why sample data and expected results are always helpful...

Comment: i tagged my question incorrectly due to not knowing how to ask. i will do a better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `case when`

```
 select t.city, case when Hot>1 then '' 
 else case when cold= total_c then 'Good' end end   as exact  
  from    
(select city,
  sum( case when weather ='Hot' then 1 else 0 end) as Hot,
  sum( case when weather='Cold' then 1 else 0 end) as cold
  from yourtable
  group by city
 ) as t
inner join (select city,count(*) as total_c from yourtable group by 
            city) t1
 on t.city=t1.city
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2b8f3/3 link for postgresql

```
city    exact
c       Good
b     
a
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b8f3b/1 link for mysql

Comment: this does not work. Do you know redshit by any chance.

Comment: @DheerajChowdaryKolli i know sql and i think this problem supposed to solve by ansii sql which is support by redshift

Comment: @DheerajChowdaryKolli could you try please my code

Comment: @DheerajChowdaryKolli hope my solution will for any product mysql or posstgresql or sql server or redshift because here i use just standard sql

Comment: @DheerajChowdaryKolli http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b8f3/1 for mssql

Comment: Seems like the city is ambiguous during the first select. Could you review.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**  (The question was originally tagged `[mysql]`, there's discussion about using `[redshit]` (sic) and the question is now tagged `[mssql]` (Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL).  MySQL Specific syntax is now removed from this answer.)

---

As another alternative <strike>(to the GROUP_CONCAT approach from Nick)</strike>, we could get a count of the number of rows, and compare that to a count of the number of rows that have `weather = 'Cold'`.  If the counts are equal, then we know all of the rows satisfy that condition.

```
 SELECT w.city
      , CASE 
        WHEN SUM(1) = SUM(CASE WHEN w.weather = 'Cold' THEN 1 END)
        THEN 'good'
        ELSE ''
        END     AS exact 
   FROM mytable w
  GROUP BY w.city
  ORDER BY w.city
```

To see how this is working, we could add some more expressions to the SELECT list

```
      , SUM(1)                                         AS count_all_rows 
      , SUM(CASE WHEN w.weather = 'Cold' THEN 1 END)   AS count_cold_rows
```

<strike>The MySQL specific `IF` function and other MySQL shorthand could be replaced with a more portable, more ANSI standards compliant `CASE` expressions, to obtain an equivalent result...</strike>

---

If we want to return the calculated value for `exact` to be on every row from the original table, we could use the query above as an inline view and do a JOIN operation ...

```
 SELECT c.city
      , c.weather
      , e.exact
   FROM mytable c
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT w.city
               , CASE 
                 WHEN SUM(1) = SUM(CASE WHEN w.weather = 'Cold' THEN 1 END)
                 THEN 'good'
                 ELSE ''
                 END     AS exact 
            FROM mytable w
           GROUP BY w.city
        ) e
     ON e.city = c.city
  ORDER BY c.city
```

Comment: does this work in sql queries.

Comment: Yes, the example `SELECT` statement syntax provided in this answer works in  MySQL versions 5.5 and later, as long as the objects exist and we have privilege on the objects. The `IF` function and some of the shorthand syntax is specific to MySQL, and would need to be tweaked/adjusted for other DBMS such as Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata, etc.

Comment: OP is actually using [Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-sql.html) (I've retagged question) so I'm not sure any of these will work. Mine certainly won't...